# Business Objects RelativeDate function Cognos Equivalent

Tags: function, report, business-objects, cognos

I am converting a report from BO to Cognos and one of the query items in BO is as follows

```
    =RelativeDate(ToDate([Full Date];"MM/dd/yyyy");-6)
```

I am looking for the Cognos equivalent of this function.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: Can you provide examples of desired input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
_add_days([Full Date],-6)
```

Answer (score 0):

That function is taking a string formatting it as a date then taking 6 days from it, the following function in Cognos should work:

```
dateadd ( ' { ' datepart ' } ' , integer_expression , date_expression )
```

So in your example, to take 6 days from today it would be

```
dateadd('dd',6,'2015-10-29')
```

This was taken from the [Cognos 10.1.0 documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.1.0.doc/ug_cr_rptstd_id56771syb_dateadd.html%23syb_dateadd)

Comment: I think that's Sybase-specific. Look at the breadcrumb navigation of the KB article. If he's using another data source it may not work. A non-vendor specific alternative would be _add_days([Full Date],-6).